# Displaying Search Fields

Tags: php

This may not be enough information for anyone to answer this, but I might just be missing something y'all would know by looking at the code.

In my site's admin panel, I can assign custom fields to categories (No. of beds, baths, whatever I create), but in order for the fields to show up on the Advanced Search page, you have to assign the field(s) to all of my sites categories.

I am trying to get the field(s) to show up all the time, even if they are only assigned to certain categories, not all of them.

Here is the code that renders the fields on the Advanced Search page, but again, only renders them if the field is assigned to all categories:

```
<?php
$get_catID = get_CATID($_GET['ad_cat_cat']);
if(empty($get_catID)) $get_catID = 0;
$get_catID = array($get_catID);
$arr = get_category_fields_without_vals($get_catID, 'no');
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$arr[$i]['field_name'].$arr[$i]['id'].':</td>';
echo '<td>'.$arr[$i]['value'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's this function here you need to look at: `get_category_fields_without_vals`

Comment: Why do you do this: `$get_catID = array($get_catID);`